# How do I get value from javascript to iphone/ipad?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I would like to get the value from Javascript which is been evoked on function click in iphone/iPad UIWebView. How can achieve this kindly provide me a snippet of both iPhone code as well as javascript code.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

in ios7 apple introduced a new frame work named [JavaScriptCore](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/WebKit_JavaScriptCore_Ref/_index.html) and you also can find some use full tutorials

[#1](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3784-javascriptcore-and-ios-7/)

[#2](http://hayageek.com/execute-javascript-in-ios/)

[#3](http://maniacdev.com/2012/03/example-javascriptcore-in-ios-apps-high-performance-html5javascript-apps-no-uiwebview)

Answer (score 0):

See the Apple Documentation on [Calling Objective-C Methods from JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html), this page has code snippets and links to further documentation.